# Mediawiki is making Apache2 crash, what can I do?

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04, mediawiki

When I call this URL : https://MyMediawikiDoma.in/index.php?title=MyArticle&type=revision&diff=3441&oldid=3424

Apache2 crash with this backtrace:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007fe6039edc8a in ?? () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#1  0x00007fe6039ee6eb in ?? () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#2  0x00007fe6039eea96 in zend_parse_parameters () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#3  0x00007fe5f1bdf268 in zif_wikidiff2_do_diff(_zend_execute_data*, _zval_struct*) () from target:/usr/lib/php/20170718/wikidiff2.so
#4  0x00007fe603a8f3fb in execute_ex () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#5  0x00007fe603a97267 in zend_execute () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#6  0x00007fe6039e59f2 in zend_execute_scripts () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#7  0x00007fe603981450 in php_execute_script () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#8  0x00007fe603a99422 in ?? () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#9  0x000055906ce68cc0 in ap_run_handler ()
#10 0x000055906ce6923d in ap_invoke_handler ()
#11 0x000055906ce80c7b in ap_process_async_request ()
#12 0x000055906ce80e50 in ap_process_request ()
#13 0x000055906ce7d21d in ?? ()
#14 0x000055906ce72ad0 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#15 0x00007fe604004831 in ?? () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#16 0x00007fe604004b34 in ?? () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#17 0x00007fe60400557e in ?? () from target:/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#18 0x000055906ce4c28e in ap_run_mpm ()
#19 0x000055906ce44b2b in main ()
```

The server runs Ubuntu 18.04 and Mediawiki from https://launchpad.net/~legoktm/+archive/ubuntu/mediawiki-lts/

What can I do to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I have uninstalled `wikidiff2` with `apt remove php-wikidiff2`. It is now running well on the internal PHP engine.

I've also open a bug report to the wikidiff2 project : https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T240620

Answer (score 0):

I would try different approaches, like:

- Don't deploy applications like MediaWiki and other web-based applications from dpkg packages. Use their official packages instead. Usually, they'll make tarballs available. The benefit you get from this approach is that you won't get dependency issues, and you'll be able to run it on Nginx and PHP-FPM, for instance;
- Use Docker and the MediaWiki Docker image.

Best regards.

Comment: 1. Tarballs is harder to maintain: How are you aware of updates ? With distribution packages, I'm perfectly able to use Nginx.
2. Docker looks like a big investment to me.

Comment: 1. I use CI/CD tools to keep everything up-to-date. Also, you could clone their git repository and just pull whenever there's a new version. But, since you're able to use Nginx, try using it with PHP-FPM.

2. Well, I'm giving possible solutions to your problem.